# Checking if an Excel Workbook is open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, excel-2007

Is there a way to see if an Excel Workbook, say DataSheet.xls, is open (in use) or not?  I would like to close that Workbook if it is opened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The right way is to examine the Application.Workbooks object. In VBA you would write:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
On Error Resume Next                       '//this is VBA way of saying "try"'
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(wbookName)
If err.Number = 9 then                     '//this is VBA way of saying "catch"'
    'the file is not opened...'
End If
```

In other words, Workbooks is an array (or in VBA terms, Collection) of all open workbooks.

In C# the following code works:

```
    static bool IsOpened(string wbook)
    {
        bool isOpened = true;
        Excel.Application exApp;
        exApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        try
        {
            exApp.Workbooks.get_Item(wbook);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            isOpened = false;
        }
        return isOpened;
    }
```

You will probably want to pass the reference to Excel.Application yourself.

Comment: C# version does not work for me at this day. Always raise an exception and return false. w69rdy solution did the trick for me.

Comment: What is the refernce for Excel.Application ?

Comment: COM -> Microsoft Excel xx.xx Object Library

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
try
{
   Stream s = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

   s.Close();

   return true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
   return false;
}
```

This will tryand open the file exclusively.  If the file is already open it will throw an exception, where you can then (try to) close it and carry on.

Comment: This would also raise errors on other problems, bot necessarily that the workbook is open.

Comment: Yes, so you check the error message to see if its the error message you're looking for, if its not simply rethrow the exception!

Comment: Its the only way you can do it, unless you've got a better suggestion ck??

Comment: If I was doing this manually, I would try to open the file in Excel, then see if I get a dialog telling me that someone else has it open.  The better answer would be to automate that.

Comment: IMHO, This is the perfect method. `Marshal.GetActiveObject` gets only objects and what if the excel is open in another object ? Great solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in a one liner that avoids using a try-catch...

```
bool wbOpened = ((Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")).Workbooks.Cast<Workbook>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Some Workbook.xlsx") != null;
```

Or with fully qualified names...

```
bool wbOpened = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")).Workbooks.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Some Workbook.xlsx") != null;
```

Of course, you may want to split this up a little. The main point is to use LINQ instead of try-catch to check for the workbook's existence.

**Note 1:** `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` will throw an error if no instance of Excel is open. So unless otherwise guarantied or handled this should always be within a try-catch.

```
bool wbOpened = false;
try
{
   wbOpened = ((Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")).Workbooks.Cast<Workbook>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Some Workbook.xlsx") != null;
}
catch
{
...
}
```

**Note 2:** `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` will only return one instance of Excel. If you need to search any possible instance of Excel then the  code below may be a better alternative.

---

**Better Alternative**

If you don't mind adding a helper class the code below may be a better alternative. Aside from being able to search any opened instance of Excel, it also allows you to check the full path and return the actual workbook object if found. It also avoids throwing an error if no instance of Excel is opened.

usage would be like this...

```
If (IsOpenedWB_ByName("MyWB.xlsx"))
{
   ....
}
```

or

```
Workbook wb = GetOpenedWB_ByPath("C:\MyWB.xlsx")
if (wb.obj == null) //If null then Workbook is not already opened
{
  ...
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

public class WBHelper
{
    public static bool IsOpenedWB_ByName(string wbName)
    {
        return (GetOpenedWB_ByName(wbName) != null);
    }

    public static bool IsOpenedWB_ByPath(string wbPath)
    {
        return (GetOpenedWB_ByPath(wbPath)  != null);
    }

    public static Workbook GetOpenedWB_ByName(string wbName)
    {
        return (Workbook)GetRunningObjects().FirstOrDefault(x => (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x.Path) == wbName) && (x.Obj is Workbook)).Obj;
    }

    public static Workbook GetOpenedWB_ByPath(string wbPath)
    {
        return (Workbook)GetRunningObjects().FirstOrDefault(x => (x.Path == wbPath) && (x.Obj is Workbook)).Obj;
    }

    public static List<RunningObject> GetRunningObjects()
    {
        // Get the table.
        List<RunningObject> roList = new List<RunningObject>();
        IBindCtx bc;
        CreateBindCtx(0, out bc);
        IRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
        bc.GetRunningObjectTable(out runningObjectTable);
        IEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
        runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
        monikerEnumerator.Reset();

        // Enumerate and fill list
        IMoniker[] monikers = new IMoniker[1];
        IntPtr numFetched = IntPtr.Zero;
        List<object> names = new List<object>();
        List<object> books = new List<object>();
        while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, numFetched) == 0)
        {
            RunningObject running;
            monikers[0].GetDisplayName(bc, null, out running.Path);
            runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out running.Obj);
            roList.Add(running);
        }
        return roList;
    }

    public struct RunningObject
    {
        public string Path;
        public object Obj;
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    static extern void CreateBindCtx(int a, out IBindCtx b);
}
```

I adapted the `GetRunningObjects()` method in the code above from [here](http://blocko.blogspot.com/2006/10/driving-excel-and-powerpoint-with-c.html).

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal not have a GetActiveObject method in NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

martin's answer does not work if Excel Application is not currently running.
You may want to modifiy the code as following :

```
static bool IsOpened(string wbook)
{
    bool isOpened = true;
    Excel.Application exApp;

    try
    {
        // place the following line here :
        exApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        // because it throws an exception if Excel is not running.
        exApp.Workbooks.get_Item(wbook);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        isOpened = false;
    }
    return isOpened;
}
```

Thank you for your attention. Regards

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to the previous C# anwsers, if somebody might stumble into this:

The method where you check:

```
    xlAppRef.Workbooks.Item
```

actually works, as long as the variable
*wbook* is "myworkbook.xlsx", **not the entire path** to the workbook (like "C/Users/Me/Desktop/myworkbook.xlsx")

```
    bool IsOpened(string wbook, Excel.Application xlAppRef)
    {
        bool isOpened = true;
        
        try
        {
            // wbook should be: "name-of-the-workbook.xlsx". Otherwise it will always raise the
            // exception and never return true
            var vb = xlAppRef.Workbooks.Item[wbook];
            
        }
        catch (Exception  e)
        {
            isOpened = false;
        }
        return isOpened;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not especially nice - we'll try and open the file and examine the exception if it fails. I'm not sure you have any other choices in C#.

However, it is important to only handle the correct exception: Basically we try open the file with no sharing allowed. If it fails, AND we get the correct type of exception AND we get the correct message in the exception,  then we know it is open.

```
// open the file with no sharing semantics (FileShare.None)
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    try
    {
        stream.ReadByte();
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // catch ONLY the exception we are interested in, and check the message too
        if (ex.Message != null 
            && ex.Message.Contains("The process cannot access the file"));
        {
            return true;
        }

        // if the message was incorrect, this was not the IOException we were looking for. Rethrow it.
        throw;
    }
}
```

Obviosuly this sort of approach is brittle with respect to the exception message being changed in a future release of .Net. You may wish to complement such functionality with a test that purposely locks a file and then calls this to check it correctly detects the message.

Comment: That does not work outside an english environment !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have worksheet and workbook objects them you can do parent check

if (sheet.Parent == workbook)

Answer (score 0):

> This function below will return you whether the excel file is open or
>   not.
>
> Second function will get you the Excel Application, Workbook & Sheet
>   to be used for your code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using wf = System.Windows.Forms;
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public static class ExcelTest
{   
    public xl.Application xlApp = null;
    public xl.Workbook xlWb = null;
    public xl.Worksheet xlWs = null;

    public static bool IsXlFileOpen(string xlFileName)
    {       
        try
        {       
            if (!File.Exists(xlFileName))
            {
                wf.MessageBox.Show("Excel File does not exists!");
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                xlApp = (xl.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (xl.Workbook wb in xlApp.Workbooks)
            {
                if (wb.FullName == xlFileName)
                {
                    xlWb = wb;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void GetXlSheet(string xlFileName,
                                    string xlSheetName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(xlFileName))
            {
                wf.MessageBox.Show("Excel File does not exists!");
                return false;
            }

            xlApp = (xl.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            foreach (xl.Workbook wb in xlApp.Workbooks)
            {
                if (wb.FullName == xlFileName)
                {
                    if (!xlWb
                        .Sheets
                        .Cast<xl.Worksheet>()
                        .Select(s => s.Name)
                        .Contains(xlSheetName))
                    {
                        wf.MessageBox.Show("Sheet name does not exist in the Excel workbook!");
                        return;
                    }
                    xlWs = xlWb.Sheets[xlSheetName];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch errors
        }
    }   
}
```